# When executing Citrus HTTP test case using "TestNGCitrusTestDesigner" getting following error ".CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to get correlation key"

Tags: testng, citrus-framework

I have set up the citrus framework and trying to execute the test case but getting error as below: 
"TEST FAILED SampleJavaIT.testResponse  Nested exception is: 
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to get correlation key for 'citrus_message_correlator_todoClient'". 
I am using "TestNGCitrusTestDesigner" as DSL.
Please help me on this. Below is code snippet.

```
@Test
@CitrusTest
 public void testResponse(){

    http().client(todoClient)
            .receive().response();

 }
```

Expected : Test case should execute successfully.

Actual: TEST FAILED SampleJavaIT.testResponse  Nested exception is: 
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to get correlation key for 'citrus_message_correlator_todoClient'

Answer (score 0):

How does your HttpClient look like? If i had to guess, the `todoClient` isn't configured properly.

Comment: this is not an answer, move this to a comment.